# Sending data from JS to Python successfully but Flask render_template doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, python, flask, post, jinja2

I am using a Jinja loop to display a table of results in an html page. When someone clicks the button in a table row, the code should send the first column value in that row to the server. The server should then use the value to populate values in another page. All works fine except the `render_template` function in `app.py` isn't executing.

What am I doing wrong?

My last `print(request_details)` shows the data needed correctly. However the `render_template` that follows just doesn't want to execute.

HTML and JS:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Request ID</th>
        <th>Origin</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Distance</th>
        <th>Cargo</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for r in supplier_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ r[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ r[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ r[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ r[4] }}</td>
        <td>{{ r[5] }}</td>
        <td><button onclick="passRequest({{ r[0]|safe }})">Offer</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<script>
    function passRequest(arg) {
        let details = arg
        console.log(details)
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.open('POST', '/viewrequest/' + details)
        request.send();
    };
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Python:

```
@app.route("/viewrequest/<int:details>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def viewrequest(details):

   # Retrieve request information with the request_id (details)
   retrieve_request = f"SELECT * FROM requests WHERE request_id='{details}';"
   cur.execute(retrieve_request)
   request_details = cur.fetchall()

   # Call the newoffer page and pass the request details
   if request_details == []:
      print("No data found")
      return
   else:
      print(request_details)
      return render_template("supplier/newoffer.html", request = request_details)
```

Comment: If the route is hitting the `if request_details == []:` then no response is sent. We don't have your database, but this is an invalid route if that branch is possible.

Comment: You're right that branch isn't possible. It was a remnant from checking if my database search returned the correct result. Still encountering my issue though. I see the correct route as a POST in my terminal however the render_template just doesn't seem to want to execute

Comment: Can you [edit] to show your actual code please? Programs don't generally just not execute code--there'd have to be an error or control flow problem. A [mcve] seems needed here to help, because right now `render_template` isn't being hit if `request_details` is empty, which is definitely an issue.

Comment: This is my actual code. The {{ print(request_details }} is executed so I know that's where it ends up.

Comment: How do you know `render_template` isn't executing then? There is no error? Does the server send a response to the client? Short of the Python interpreter instantly crashing and kicking you back to the command line, there's basically no way `render_template` wouldn't run if the `print` above it does.

Comment: I know I am as confused as you. If render_template were to execute, a new HTML page would appear, but it isn't. There are no errors sent and the server response is 200